# PHP/Ajax /JQuery response not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have **index.php** file which is as following :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="summary">The returned value will go here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The content of **ajax.js** which is supposed to keep calling/invoking function.php until function.php returns '1' :

```
function check(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'function.php',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(response){
            if(response == '1'){
                $('#summary').html(response);
            }else{
                check();
            }
        },
        failure: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
}

check();
```

And Finally **function.php** :

```
<?php
  echo "1";
?>
```

I  expected that function.php would only be invoked once since function.php returns "1". However it keeps calling **function.php** endlessly.

Can someone point me out how to get this working properly?

Comment: can you log/alert the value of `response` in the success handler

Comment: the given code looks fine....

Comment: Check for whitespace before and after the PHP tags in function.php. Edit: If response is always numerical, you can also do an implicit conversion by changing the if condition to `== 1` instead of `== '1'`.

Comment: Try `if(response.trim() == '1'){` and add `alert(':' + response + ':')` before the `if` stmt

Comment: @naohnu : Thanks, it appeared php was indeed adding whitespaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, but 1 probable reason is the response might have leading or trailing spaces.

A solution could be is to trim the response value before comparing it

```
if (response.trim() == '1') {//use $.trim(response) if wants to support < IE9 or use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill)
    $('#summary').html(response);
} else {
    check();
}
```